# Jersey client and com.sun package

Tags: java, jersey

Jersey client resides in com.sun.* package where we mostly have internal classes and should be avoided.

Hence should we still be using jersey or think of alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same thing. What you want to avoid is `com.sun` from the standard language library. Jersey is not part of the Java standard library.

> *"should we still be using jersey or think of alternatives"*.

`com.sun.jersey` is part of the Jersey 1.x. People are still using it. But Jersey has version 2.x which is the newer version (packages start with `org.glassfish.jersey`). If you are starting a new project, better to start with version 2.x.

But as far as the `com.sun` packing naming, it does not fall in the same category as the "should avoid" standard Java libraries. Jersey 1.x is still fine to use.

**See also:**

- [Jersey Getting Started Guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/getting-started.html) for Jersey 2.x